# Why am I getting an "Invalid token" when requesting the cube.js API?

Tags: cube.js

I have deployed cube.js via a Helm chart I've created to an AWS EKS cluster.  One of the first errors I encountered was that the environment variable `CUBEJS_API_SECRET` is required.  In a docker-compose deployment this secret is automatically generated, but OK, I made an AWS Secrets Manager secret comprised of a random 256-bit string, and synced this with a Kubernetes secret injected into the API service pod as `CUBEJS_API_SECRET`.  I can `exec` into the API service pod and echo this variable to confirm it is saved correctly.

I am trying to test the deployment by `curl`ing the API service:

```sh
> $ curl -vvv -H "Authorization: <The API token I generate below>" -G --data-urlencode 'query={"measures":["EventAuthentication.count"]}' localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/load
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:4000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4000 (#0)
> GET /cubejs-api/v1/load?query=%7B%22measures%22%3A%5B%22EventAuthentication.count%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4000
> User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: <The API token I generate below>
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 25
< ETag: W/"19-1luTU257I9tvKUXOJotGBQDVDqk"
< Date: Tue, 20 Dec 2022 21:58:05 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"Invalid token"}
```

I am not quite sure why this token is invalid.  I can enter the token and the `CUBEJS_API_SECRET` at https://jwt.io/ and the website says that the token is valid.

I am following the [documentation](https://cube.dev/docs/security#generating-token) on generating this token.  This is the script I use (exactly as the documentation suggests):

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const CUBE_API_SECRET = '<the CUBEJS_API_SECRET environment variable>';

const cubejsToken = jwt.sign({}, CUBE_API_SECRET, { expiresIn: '30d' });
console.log(cubejsToken);
```

I have asked this question of the cube.js Slack organization and no one is responding: what am I missing and why is this token invalid?  It appears that I am following the documentation correctly, and I have no further information from pod logs or the response as to why the token is invalid.

A second question is, what even is this `CUBEJS_API_SECRET` environment variable?  The documentation on this is sparse: "The secret key used to sign and verify JWTs. Generated on project scaffold with `npx cubejs-cli create`."

Comment: Are you simply missing the `Bearer` prefix to identify the token type?

Comment: @Phil There is no `Bearer` prefix; see the example curl command at this page: https://cube.dev/docs/security/context

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

It requires you to pass in some form of user credentials to be combined with the API secret while generating a jwt token ([https://cube.dev/docs/security/context#:~:text=API%20token%20as-,follows,-%3A](https://cube.dev/docs/security/context#:%7E:text=API%20token%20as-,follows,-%3A)). Try this:

```
    const payload = {
             accessToken: insert user accessToken if any,
             clientId/userId: insert clientId or userId if any,
         };

 return jwt.sign(
         payload,
         CUBEJS_API_SECRET,
         { expiresIn: '1800s' },
     );
 }
```